# UITextView the text is going out of the box

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, uitextfield, ios-autolayout

I am working on a chat app. The message box resizes according to the length of the text, but the text is going out of the box when the line breaks.

[image: Print's]

I tried adding `textView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero` in `textViewDidChange` method, but it continues to not work.

The function:

```
func textViewDidChange(textView: UITextView) {

    let minSize = CGFloat(50)
    let maxSize = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height - 50 - keyboardHeight
    let expectedSize = textView.contentSize.height + 9

    var newSize = expectedSize < minSize ? minSize : expectedSize
    newSize = newSize > maxSize ? maxSize : newSize

    acessoryViewH.constant = newSize

    textView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
}
```

The auto-layout constraints:

[image: Constraint's]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `textView.layer.masksToBounds = true`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I've edited the answer. It's `masksToBounds` of course.

Comment: Thanks, it's is partially correct, but now instead of the text going out of the box, it is with the top cut.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `textView.clipsToBounds = true`

Comment: This is currently in viewDidLoad method

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in textViewDidBeginEditing delegate. It is work for me.

```
textView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
```

in viewDidload

```
[textView setClipsToBounds:YES];
```